# I want to instantiate an object at the location of another object which is destroyed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am destroying two objects and when they are destroyed I want to instantiate an object at the same location.

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameManager instance;
    public GameObject prefab;

    public void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        Check();
    }

    public void Check()
    {
        if (MagnetBehaviour.instance.isConnected == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Check");
            MagnetBehaviour.instance.isConnected = false;
            Instantiate(prefab);

            Debug.Log(MagnetBehaviour.instance.isConnected);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your definition of "same location"? How do you "destroy" the objects? Both are usually things you got no control over in .NET, as having to manage these detail prooved problematic in C-style langauages over decades.

Comment: When two objects come at a certain distance. I am destroying both the object at that moment. And when they are destroyed, I want to instantiate an object where the objects are destroyed.

Comment: So what exactly are you having issues with?  what have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything. Because I can't find a way to start.

Comment: Hi Aman. See, words like "object" and "destroy an object" have specific meanings in programming / CS. If you are talking about "logical" or "domain" objects, you should make that explicit to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: But to the topic: Your example code shows nothing that would help us help you. If you want to do anything in regard to a position, your classes need to have properties that represent a position. Do they?

Answer (score 3):

You should clarify in your question that you are using Unity3D and that the objects you are referring to are Gameobjects in Unity3D.

In your code where you call the Destroy(myGameobject) you can also instantiate the new gameobject you want.

Something like this.

```cs
public Gameobject myNewGameObjectPrefab; //drag your prefab here in the inspector

void DestroyAndCreate(Gameobject myGameObject)
{
    GameObject newObj = Instantiate(myNewGameObjectPrefab, myGameobject.transform.position);
    Destroy(myGameobject);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to cache the position of the object before it gets destroyed and instantiate the object that you want to spawn with the cached position. This following script would work for position only. (Untested)

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameManager instance;
    public GameObject prefabToDestroy;
    public GameObject prefabToSpawn;

    public void Start()
    {
       DestroyAndSpawn(prefabToDestroy, prefabToSpawn);
    }

    public void DestroyAndSpawn(GameObject prefabToDestroy, GameObject prefabToSpawn)
    {
       Vector3 position = prefabToDestroy.transform.position;
       Destroy(prefabToDestroy);
       Instantiate<GameObject>(prefabToSpawn, position, Quaternion.Identity);
    }
}
```

If you want the spawned object to have the same rotation as the destroyed one, you can also cache the rotation and replace the Quaternion.Identity with this rotation.

Comment: So the thing is.. I am instantiating the object which is going to be destroyed. How should I cache the location of that.

Comment: Basically the same process, just use the objects position before it is destroyed. It does not make a difference if you use the position of another object or the one thats being destroyed. The thing that matters is that you save the location of the object before calling Destroy()

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a script like this to the object you intend to destroy

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DestroyableObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool Destroyed { get;  set; }

    public Vector3 Position { get; set; }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        Position = transform.position;
        Destroyed = true;
    }
}
```

Then in your code

```
public DestroyableObject obj1;
public DestroyableObject obj2;

public void Check()
{
    if (obj1.Destroyed && obj2.Destroyed)
    {
        Instantiate(prefab, obj1.Position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```